# setInterval stopping prematurely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to increment the width of a div every half a second. It should continue to expand as long as it is less than 100% wide. However, it is stopping at `10%`:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/vkcd4/1/)

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var progress = setInterval(function(){
         if( $(".bar").css('width') < '100%') {
            $('.bar').animate({ width: '+=10%' });
    } else {

        clearInterval(progress);
    }
    }, 500) 
});
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: Hint: You're comparing *strings*

Comment: Also, are you intentionally animating in segments rather than just animating it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, simply compares bar to it's parent width:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    var $bar = $(".bar"),
        parentW = $bar.parent().width();
    var progress = setInterval(function () {
        if ($bar.width() < parentW) {
            $bar.animate({
                width: '+=10%'
            });
        } else {

            clearInterval(progress);
        }
    }, 500)
});
```

The problem with approach you had is `css('width')` returns string width including `px` and comparing that to string `100%` wasn't working .

Easy check to see what it looks like:

```
console.log($bar.css('width'))
```

Note that `jQuery.width()` returns numerical value of pixel width

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vkcd4/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why are you playing with % of width. Just make it simple.

For example :

increase the width by 10px each time while width is less than 100.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var progress = setInterval(function(){
        var width=$(".bar").width();
         if( width < 100) {
            $('.bar').animate({ width: width + 10 });
    } else {
        clearInterval(progress);
    }
    }, 500) 
});
```

Check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vkcd4/2/)

Comment: You're assuming his final width should be 100px. Your direction is right, though. Only instead of 10 and 100, I'd use variables that contain the value to increment by (possible the target width * .1) and the target width (the width of the container).

Comment: Eran's right, this is the right direction, but I'm relying on a percentage width. Would it be possible to use this with percentages?

Comment: yup thats why i have written in first line don't play width %. i.e change the value of 100% and 10% to a simple integer. As an example i have shown 10 and 100.